# CLI: How to set a folder's permissions the same as existing adjacent folders?

Tags: permissions

I know how to set permissions etc, but rather than:

1. Check permissions of one existing folder; and
2. Note them down somewhere; and
3. Use a command to set the permissions of an adjacent folder to the ones I've noted down

I want to run a command to set permissions of [folder 313] exactly the same as [folder 128].

Ideally, I would be able to set more than one, such that I can set the permissions of [folder 313], [folder 179], [folder 54], and [folder 226] simultaneously with the same permissions as [folder 128].

Comment: What OS exactly? does its version of `chmod` support a `--reference=RFILE` option?

Comment: As mentioned in don_crissti's link as well as cloning permissions you can also clone the owner of a file or folder using `chown --reference=RFILE`. And FWIW, GNU `touch` also supports the `--reference` option, so you can clone timestamps, too.

Comment: Thanks. It's all fixed now.

I can't work out how to mark this question as "answered", but it is.